# How to bypass ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION error?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I am using Chrome v48 and I am getting an error:

> ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION

I understand the reason for the error (server is using an unsupported SSL version; SSLv3 I am guessing). However, it is a website within an internal network and I do not have control over the server.

How to make an exception for a single domain or simply enable SSLv3 support in the latest Chrome version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Chrome with the `--ssl-version-fallback-min=ssl3` option.

Note that SSLv3 support will soon be removed from code entirely; if you must use old devices, install an older version of Firefox/SeaMonkey alongside. (Be sure to use the official binary bundle, not a distro package, since you'll need an older libnss as well, not only the browser.)